# Google Chart Add Color Specific

Tags: html, charts, colors, google-visualization, pie-chart

How are you?

How do I force the color? I do not want them to be random. I read the documentation, but something is wrong. I can not tell. They help me? Thank you very much!

For Example: I want the Womens records in Black and the mens in Green.

Regarts!

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});  
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
   function drawChart()  
   {  
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
     ['status', 'number',{ role: 'style' },{ role: 'annotation' } ],  
    ["Men", 5, '#b87333','M'],
     ["Girl", 7, '#0000FF','G'],
        ]);  
    var options = {  
     title: 'Sex',  
     is3D:true,  
     pieHole: 0.4,
     //colors: ['#5cb85c','#f0ad4e']
     
    };  
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));  
    chart.draw(data, options);  
   }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> </script>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only `role` supported by `PieChart` is `'tooltip'`

both `'style'` and `'annotation'` **are not supported**

you can either use the `colors` configuration option,

```
colors: ['#5cb85c','#000000']
```

or the `slices` option...

```
slices: [{color: '#5cb85c'}, {color: '#000000'}]
```

in both options above, the first color in the array will be applied to the first row in the data table,
the second color, the second row, etc...

if you're not sure in which order the data will be,
you can use an object to map the values to a specific color

here, we build the array of colors, by matching the values in the data table,
to the key in the color map object...

```
var colors = [];
var colorMap = {
  'Men': '#5cb85c',
  'Girl': '#000000'
}
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  colors.push(colorMap[data.getValue(i, 0)]);
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['status', 'number'],
    ['Men', 5],
    ['Girl', 7]
  ]);

  var colors = [];
  var colorMap = {
    'Men': '#5cb85c',
    'Girl': '#000000'
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    colors.push(colorMap[data.getValue(i, 0)]);
  }

  var options = {
    title: 'Sex',
    is3D: true,
    colors: colors
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> </script>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="piechart"></div>
```