# fixed color for each elements of Google pie chart

Tags: google-visualization, google-pie-chart

i have this array in my script

```
colors: ['#4285F4', '#007E33', '#FF8800', '#ff4444']
```

i need to fixed color for each element like 
Male color : Blue
female color : red

Comment: see this answer --> [Google Chart Add Color Specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080746/5090771)