# Dynamically change colors of google pie chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, pie-chart, dynamically-generated

I am using google pie chart how can I set colors when my data comes dynamically.
I am using below logic to set colors

```
var options = {
  width: 400,
  height: 240,
  title: 'Toppings I Like On My Pizza',
  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
};

chart.draw(data, options);
```

but in these case the data is comes in 5 array but how to handle when data is dynamically comes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you need to use a color map, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080746/5090771)? or are you more concerned with the number of colors / rows?